# NestJS with Docker and Portainer

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, portainer

i'm trying to turn UP my project with a Virtual Private Server. I've installed Docker and Portainer and i can start the project. But its not running in any port. I did set to run in port 3000 but when i put in browser IP_Of_My_VPS:3000 nothing happens. I'm new with docker and every configuration that i did was based on my searchs.

[image]

This print shows that image is running in no one port.

[image]

This other print shows that my application is running (but i dont know how access it).

My docker config:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN apk --no-cache add git
RUN git --version

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build && rm -rf src

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s --start-period=30s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:3000/health || exit 1

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./dist/main.js"]
```

Comment: You didn't tell portainer to expose your app. You can see that in your first screenshot. There are no ports.

Answer (score 0):

When docker container up, perform port forwarding

for examples,

```
docker run -p <your_forwarding_port>:3000 ~~~
```

```
# docker-compose.yaml
~~~
     ports:
       - "<your_forwarding_port>:3000"
~~~
```

you can see ref 
: [docker-container port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) 
: [docker-compose port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Comment: I create a new container and did a different configuration in Portainer and i openned with success the port 3000 .

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vxhs6z here shows that port is open .
however, when i tried to access MY_VPS_IP:3000 i receive ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED .

Comment: what is MY_VPS_IP?? and, Where are you making the connection request?

Comment: MY_VPS_IP is a placeholder of IP of my Virtual Private Server .

I found the problem. It was generated by Fastify (for some reason, fastify was rejecting any connection). I removed it and everything works fine :)

Thanks for your attention and help ^^